# Triangular grid, one half is wrong

Tags: opengl, grid

I am trying to create triangular grid with sorted triangles in OpenGL. I have vertices buffer and indices buffer. I was partialy succesfull, but one half of grid is rendering wrong as you can see on screenshot. I cant figure out why is that.

[image]

My code is here

```
float[] vertices = new float[2 * rows * columns];

        int counter = 0;
        for(int r = 0; r <rows; r++){
            for(int c = 0; c < columns; c++){
                vertices[counter ++] = (float)r / (rows-1);
                vertices[counter ++] = (float)c / (columns -1);             
            }
        }

int[] indices = new int[4 * (rows) * (columns)];

        int counter = 0;
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
            for(int c =0; c <= columns; c++){
                if(r % 2 == 0){
                    if(c == columns){
                        indices[counter ++] = (c-1) + (r+1)*columns;
                        indices[counter ++] = (c-1) + (r+1)*columns;
                    }else{
                        indices[counter ++] = c + r * columns;  
                        indices[counter ++] = c + (r+1) * columns;  
                    }
                }else{
                    if(c == columns){
                        indices[counter ++] = (columns) - c + (r +1) * columns;
                        indices[counter ++] = (columns) - c + (r +1) * columns;
                    }else{
                        indices[counter ++] = (columns - 1) - c + (r + 1) * columns;
                        indices[counter ++] =  r*columns + (columns-1) - c;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I recommend you read about primitive restart index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (int r = 0; r < rows - 1; r++) {` is what you actually want.

You are using `(r+1)` rows while looping from `r = 0` to `r = (rows - 1)`, effectively ending up in a non-existent row filled with zeroes.

So this is not a «half of the grid», it`s just the final row of triangles.

And BTW, `4 * rows * columns` is too much for a list of triangle strip indices with 2 additional degenerate triangles between strips; `2 * (columns + 1) * (rows - 1)` shall be enough.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solves the problem, I realy didn´t realize that problem is only at last row.